# prstat in Ubuntu or Centos

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, centos

As the *Java Performance* said:

> Solaris prstat has additional capabilities 
>   such as reporting both user and kernel or system CPU utilization along with other 
>   microstate information using the prstat -m and -L options. The -m option prints 
>   microstate information, and -L prints statistics on per lightweight process.

There is any tool available like prstat in Centos or Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Linux commands you are looking for are **top** and **pstree** .

Here is **ptree** for Linux,

```
#!/bin/sh
# Solaris style ptree

[ -x /usr/bin/ptree ] && exec /usr/bin/ptree "$@"

# Print process tree
# $1 = PID : extract tree for this process
# $1 = user : filter for this (existing) user
# $1 = user $2 = PID : do both

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH

psopt="-e"
case $1 in
[a-z]*) psopt="-u $1";shift;;
esac

[ -z "$1" ] &&
exec ps $psopt -Ho pid=,args=

#some effort to add less to the ps list
tmp=/tmp/ptree.$$
trap 'rm $tmp' 0 HUP INT TERM
ps $psopt -Ho pid=,args= >$tmp
<$tmp awk '
{ ci=index(substr($0,7),$2); o[ci]=$0 }
ci>s[a] { s[++a]=ci }
$1==pid {
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++) {
            si=s[i]; if(si<=ci) print o[si]
    }
    walkdown=ci
            next
}
ci<walkdown { exit }
walkdown!=0 { print }
' pid="$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no prstat "equivalent" tool in Linux. You can use a combination of top and ps (or /proc/$pid/ resources) to get some useful result; maybe writing a shell script (using grep, sed and awk) which collects results from above commands and files.
Just for reference I found this link about top command and kernel, user and idle CPU utilization intresting

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/02/24/understanding-linuxs-cpu-stats

Hope this helps.